# range.formulas assignment is not updating the Formula Bar in Excel add-in

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-app

I'm in an Excel web Add-in (office-js), in a .xlsx file

In **Range C3: C6** there are formulas that in the same type VLOOKUP

[Snapshot of before code execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miIxf.png)

And In `index.js` my code is

```
let data=[
  ["=INDEX(R2C11:R9C11,MATCH(R[0]C2,R2C10:R9C10,0))"],
  ["=INDEX(R2C11:R9C11,MATCH(R[0]C2,R2C10:R9C10,0))"],
  ["=INDEX(R2C11:R9C11,MATCH(R[0]C2,R2C10:R9C10,0))"],
  ["=INDEX(R2C11:R9C11,MATCH(R[0]C2,R2C10:R9C10,0))"],
]
range.formulasR1C1 = data;      // Here range is C3: C6
range.select();
return ctx.sync();
```

Before the code above runs, the **range C3: C6 is selected**, it looks like the first picture.

So I expect after the code execution, the formula in the **Formula Bar to update itself automatically.**

[What I've hoped for - an updated formula bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/687aE.png)

But that doesn't happen and it fails to update the Formula bar.

[What I'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fjIR.png)

**Only if** I select another cell or range, and then, re-select the **Range C3: C6**, the formulas in Formula Bar shows the Right Formula.

Can Anyone tell me what should I do? thx!

Comment: It looks like you're assigning formulas before selecting the range - perhaps that's it?

Comment: @MaviDomates Thank u for replying. I have tried the order that Firstly,  select the range, and Secondly assign the formulas, but No luck, still Doesn't update the Formula Bar Automatically.

Comment: Actually here's an interesting thought. After the assignment, if you read the contents of the cells again (in the code) do you see what you've updated / or what's there before the update. I'm trying to understand if it's writing but not updating the UI

Comment: Oh - the last bit I've re-read. So it is updating the formulas assigned to those cells, just not the formula bar! Interesting. So there's probably a bug in terms of updating the display. Can you try (programmatically) selecting another group of cells and then re-selecting the same cells which you changed the formula? Does that refresh?

Comment: Yes. After assigning the formulas, If I select another group of cells (or range) and then re-select the same cells. The Formula Bar shows the right formulas as we expect. I also think this is a bug.